# No provider for RouterOutletMap

Tags: angular

## Newest Angular 2.0.0 and via newest angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.14, node: 6.6.0, os: linux x64

## What I do:

1) Create new project

```
ng new angular-test
ng g component projects
ng g component typings
```

2) Add simple routing

/src/app/app.component.html

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

/src/app/app.module.ts

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/projects',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'projects',
    component: ProjectsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '/typings',
    component: TypingsComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**', redirectTo: ''
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProjectsComponent,
    TypingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

## What I get:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:3:0 caused by: No provider for RouterOutletMap!
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for RouterOutletMap!
```

[image]

## How I tried to fix this

I tried to add RouterOutletMap to providers in AppModule, exception don't throw, but app don't redirect to projects and don't show nesting components

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to call `RouterModule.forRoot` for the app module, not `forChild`. The former [adds all the core providers](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0/modules/%40angular/router/src/router_module.ts#L136), while [the latter doesn't](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0/modules/%40angular/router/src/router_module.ts#L157). You should use `forChild` for child modules, not the app module.

Comment: Hi I'm running into this same problem, and I have `.forRoot` being used. Mind a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321705/how-to-fix-error-in-app-app-component-html151-caused-by-no-provider-for-rout

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and . this is how i avoid that..... some time this will be helped.
best wishes!

*The Routing array* -- **app.routes.ts**

```
const appRoutes:Routes =[
 {
   path: 'home',
   component: CarouselComponent
 },
 {
  path: 'profile',
  component:UserDashboardComponentComponent,
  children: [
     {
      path: 'overview',
      component: ProfileOverviewComponent
     },
     {
      path: 'post',
      component: PostAddComponent
     }
    ]
   }
];

 export const WebRouting: ModuleWithProviders =RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  CarouselComponent,
  .......
],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  MdTabsModule,
  MaterialModule,
  MdInputModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  WebRouting
],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**tempale.html**

```
  <li>
    <a [routerLink]="['/profile/overview']" routerLinkActive="active" > 
      Overview
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a [routerLink]="['/profile/post']"routerLinkActive="active">
      PostAdd
    </a>
  </li>
```