# How to fix: Error in app/app.component.html:15:1 caused by: No provider for RouterOutletMap

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

[image]

I found these answers here, but they did not help me. I guess Angular 2 is still in flux?

[No provider for RouterOutletMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546278/no-provider-for-routeroutletmap)

[Getting Angular2 error 'No provider for Router! (RouterOutlet -> Router)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187235/getting-angular2-error-no-provider-for-router-routeroutlet-router)

#### My app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
];

export const appRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

#### app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { appRouting } from './app.routing';
import { TemplateFormComponent } from './template/template-form.component';
import { ReactiveFormComponent } from './reactive/reactive-form.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AboutComponent,
        ContactComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### My app.component.ts and it's template file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './shared/models/user';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

---

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Scotch.io</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

#### What I've tried:

`ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`

[image]

Comment: What versions on angular and angular router do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import your `appRouting` module, instead of RouterModule:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        appRouting,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
```

Add the `routerLink` attribute to your links:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a routerLink="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Don't forget you need a base tag in your HTML page:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <base href="/" />
```

Comment: Ah thanks! So also turns out I don't even need `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'` in my app.module.ts